# Error: Query was empty

Tags: php, sql

```
$nam=$_POST['name'];
$fname=$_POST['family'];
$dat=$_POST['date'];
$bal=$_POST['balance'];
$curr=$_POST['currency'];
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
$db=mysql_select_db('users',$con);
$ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Name, FamilyName, Date, Balance, Currency) VALUES  ('$nam', '$fname', '$dat', '$bal', '$curr'))",$con);
 if (!mysql_query($ins,$con))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
}
```

So guys, I got this code and I am trying to do something like a registration form. I have tripple checked the names of the variables and the query itself is working when executed in SQL database. The thing is when I include it in my php script it returns that the Query was empty. I've looked around but all errors on the Web are around not assigning to a variable or having several insert statements and so on. So my question is why am i getting this when I am actually inputting data from a web form? Error: Query was empty

P.S. 
Ok so what I mde of this: I removed the check that you said was for a second time that is the if (!mysql_query($ins,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con)); } part now i get execution but it does not really add the entry to the database and i cannot call it. That is the new name.

Comment: `mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') or die(mysql_error());` and `mysql_select_db('users') or die(mysql_error());` go

Comment: Do the same thing, for `mysql_query()`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` functions instead. And use prepared statements, your queries are vulnerable to SQL injections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically trying to use `mysql_query()` twice:

```
$ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Name, FamilyName, Date, Balance, 
Currency) VALUES  ('$nam', '$fname', '$dat', '$bal', '$curr'))",$con);

if (!mysql_query($ins,$con))
{
```

`$ins` will contain a valid MySQL resource if the query was executed correctly, but you're attempting to use it again in the `if` condition.

Just remove the `mysql_query()` part from the condition, like so:

```
if(!$ins) {
    # code ...
}
```

That should fix *this* particular issue. But note that your code is vulernable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com). Also, `mysql_*`  functions are deprecated and are soon to be removed. I recommend you switch to MySQLi or PDO and start using parameterized queries to be safe.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 This is what I get now by testing the Query. And i do not have any ) anywhere near line 1 you can check the upper code .

Answer (score 0):

this is incorrect

```
 if (!mysql_query($ins,$con))
```

why are you performing a query of a query ??

just use   `if (!$ins||!$con))` if you are trying to check if the query and connection has been successful